# How are users tracked for location based push notifications?

Tags: azure, push-notification, uwp

I want to enable push notifications for a UWP mobile app connected to Azure app service with Azure SQL database.  The notifications will alert only the users that are located within x kilometres from a certain geo coordinate.

However I'm not clear about how to track the users,  My questions are as follows,

In my database should I store every user that uses the app and update their location periodically?  I'm guessing I would need to do this in order to calculate which ones are in range and send notification to only those.  However this leads me to my next question,

If I was going to store a record for each user in my database, what identifier is used for them?  How are users identified on each device?  Do they need to log in with an authorization provider like Facebook, Twitter, etc. in order for my app to record a unique identifier? Or is there a different mechanism to create or get a unique identifier?

Answer (score 1):

@DaveSmits is on the right direction. You could register a [GeofenceBackgroundtask](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Geolocation/cs/BackgroundTask/GeofenceBackgroundTask.cs) to report user's location to your azure service. Besides current location, you also need to report current device channel Uri to your zaure device.

I believe you're familiar with [WNS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview). If not, please check that document, it will explain what the channel Uri for you.

Then in your azure service, you need to save the location and channel Uri in some database tables. You would need to caculate the distance from a certain geo coordinate. If it meets the requirement, you can get all qualified channel Uris.(e.g. `select channelUri from yourtable where location='xxxxx'`)

After you get all channel Uris, you could use it to send notifications to the specific users. About how to send notification, please check the WNS document.

I've answered a similar question on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6a7b2de2-3d8b-4226-a6f1-bd52416bbf53/uwpshared-azure-tables-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop#a4975f10-7b83-4c3d-85df-af7115f4e93a), it also needs to send notifications to the specific users.

Comment: pulling out device location via a background task, is that even possible? Because I tried to do so but the windows doesn't allow background tasks to send location data. More about this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/guidelines-and-checklist-for-detecting-location  it explicitly states the app must be in foreground

Comment: What about this scenario - a weather app that requires user to log in and set their Home Location.  Then sending notification based on saved home location (not current position). How to link channel Uri to individual user (not device) - for example get the users based on home location from user table, then send only those users a notification based on their Channel Uri.

Comment: @erotavlas If the `home location` is setted by user. You might need to think about [Convert addresses to geographic locations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/geocoding), then you could post the coordinates info to your azure service. About `How to link channel Uri to individual user (not device)`, I should have explained in my above reply, the channel Uri is unique for each device. Please read [WNS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview) more carefully.

Comment: How to handle this situation "We do not guarantee that the notification channel URI for an app will always remain the same. We advise that the app requests a new channel every time it runs and updates its service when the URI changes" ?  I don't get how this will work if the channel Uri changes in Azure.  It cannot send the notification to the users who haven't run the app to obtain new channel Uri.

Comment: @erotavlas `Notification channels automatically expire after 30 days` Please read [How to request, create, and save a notification channel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465412.aspx)

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I understand and read that part, the problem I am thinking about is storing the channel Uri in the database for each user along with their location.  If the app requests new channel Uri and it changes, how to handle this on the database side.  If I send push notification to user based on location, the channel Uri I get from the database query (based on location) will no longer be valid - I'll be sending notification to channel Uri that expired.  Should I compare old Uri to new one and update database column periodically with new one? Is that a reasonable solution?

Comment: ohh, @erotavlas my above reply was just a thinking, you could add other field in your database table. For example, your table could contain channelUrl, User IDs and location etc. Then when you get channelUrl in your app, you could compare it with localsettings. If it's updated, you could post the new channelUrl and a "update" command or other commands to your cloud service. Your cloud service could update the channel via command and User IDs.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing to track the location of the user in the push notifications. There are two things you can do:

solution 1:
- use a geofence that triggers a background task. If entering a geofence register for push notifications. If leaving the geofence unsubscribe again in your backend.

solution 2:
- Only send raw notifications and use a background task to handle them. In the background task evaulate the current location and if in the right location trigger the notification from code.